# django haystack - using a generic Views function to do search

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-haystack

I'm trying to convert this code from haystack into urls.py calling a generic view function, but I'm getting **'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'**. I think it's because it's not returning a response object.

haystack code:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm, HighlightedSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView

sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(author='john')

# With threading...
from haystack.views import SearchView, search_view_factory

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', search_view_factory(
        view_class=SearchView,
        template='search/search.html',
        searchqueryset=sqs,
        form_class=HighlightedSearchForm
    ), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

My new urls.py just calls search() in views.py.

In views.py, I have

```
def search(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
    return search_view_factory(
        view_class=SearchView,
        template='search/search.html',
        searchqueryset=sqs,
        form_class=HighlightedSearchForm
        )
```

I'm doing this because I want to mess around with sqs quite a bit depending on user inputs and status.

Shouldn't search_view_factory above return a SearchView class, seems like it calls create_response() automatically which returns render_to_response. Tried calling create_response() manually, but that wasn't working either.

[django-haystack code](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/views.py) can be found here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `search_view_factory` returns a view function instead of an `HttpResponse`, you need to invoke it properly.

```
def search(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
    view = search_view_factory(
        view_class=SearchView,
        template='search/search.html',
        searchqueryset=sqs,
        form_class=HighlightedSearchForm
        )
    return view(request)
```

Sorry for misleading in your previous question, I've fixed it also.

Comment: When using the technique mentioned in ur answer and I am facing a problem. It keeps on giving me No results in the view. Although when printing the sqs, I do get result. Any Ideas why is that happening ??

Comment: @SalmaHamed sounds like something incorrect w/ the search form or there is indeed no result for certain keywords. Could you elaborate it by a question?